# find one same element among several object

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, geometry

Currently I am doing a work related to polygons. Polygon can be described as several vertices.

```
struct Polygon{
   vector<Point2D> vertex;
   Color color;
};
```

Now, I have some polygons already **vector<Polygon> polygons**

and a method can tell me that a point is inside which polygon

```
Polygon queryPolygon(Point2D point);
```

I need to set the color of the returned polygon.

**My first question** is how to know whether the returned polygon is inside **vector<Polygon> polygons**, the one I already have.

My first idea is to use **unordered_set** and compare **(vertex.begin(), vertex.end())**. I don't know whether there is any better idea.

**Another question** is some polygon might contain the same edge. How to design the data structure so that I can know the polygons that contains same edge like

```
vector<Polygon> queryPolygonWithSameEdge(Point2D edgeStart, Point2D edgeEnd);
```

of course brute-force is one way, but is there any better ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: If you give your polygons unique IDs (addresses can also be used as IDs) the first problem becomes trivial. For the second problem you might consider a `std::multimap<Edge, Polygon*>` where `Edge` is a pair of points. Either make sure `Edge` is always sorted according to some method or insert both `Point2D` permutations to make an edge.

Comment: You need to clarify your first question: 1) do you consider the polygon as a surface (point anywhere within the boundaries set by the vertexes) or as a set of edges (only the points on the edges) ? 2) what happens if the queried point is outside any of the known polygons ? 3) does the query return one of the existing polygons, or might it create a new one defined by the closest vertexes ? or by intersection of existing polygons ?

Answer (score 0):

### First question

There are some unclear aspects about this first question (see my comments).   I'll nevertheless answer, assuming that you want just to compare an arbitrary polygon returned by the query with known polygons stored in your vector, with something like:

```
auto f = find_if (v.begin(), v.end(), [&p](const auto &x) { return compare1(x.vertex, p.vertex); });
if (f!=v.end()) {
    cout << "Found at "<< f-v.begin() <<endl; 
}
else cout << "Not found";
```

**Comparing polygons (level 1)**

The first level would be to compare point by point.  The problem, is that the ordering of points does matter, because with exactly the same points, you can draw a [pentagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon) or a [pentagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagram),  just depending on the order chosen and whether or not you accept [self-intersecting polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_self-intersecting_polygons).

For simply comparing if the vertexes in the two vectors are the same:

```
bool compare1(const vector<Point2D> &x, const vector<Point2D> &y ) {
    return x==y;  
}
```

Unfortunately,  this will not work if you have two identical polygones, that are just represented using a different starting point.

**Comparing polygons (level 2)**

Here we take care of a potential different starting point.  So the first thing is to find the offset of the first point of the fist polygon in the second polygon, and perform the comparison by taking care of the offset.  If the point is not found in the seond polygon, they are not the same:

```
bool compare2(const vector<Point2D> &x, const vector<Point2D> &y ) {
    if (x.size() != y.size())   // if different size it's not the same
        return false; 
    auto offset = find (y.cbegin(), y.cend(), x[0]);  // asumes at least 1 point 
    if (offset==y.cend()) 
        return false; 
    return equal(offset, y.cend(), x.cbegin()) 
              && equal(y.cbegin(), offset, x.cbegin()+(y.cend()-offset));  
}
```

**Comparing polygons (level 3)**

Now, it's also possible that the points are the same, but the first polygon goes clockwise and the second anticlockwise.  So we need to check in both direction:

```
bool compare3(const vector<Point2D> &x, const vector<Point2D> &y ) {
    if (x.size() != y.size())
        return false; 
    auto offset = find (y.cbegin(), y.cend(), x[0]);  // asumes at least 1 point 
    if (offset==y.cend())                             // no point in commont
        return false; 
    else if (equal(offset, y.cend(), x.cbegin()) 
              && equal(y.cbegin(), offset, x.cbegin()+(y.cend()-offset)))
        return true;  
                                                   // not equal.  And in reverse order ? 
    auto roffset = make_reverse_iterator(offset+1);
    return equal(roffset, y.crend(),  x.cbegin())
              && equal(y.crbegin(), roffset, x.cbegin()+(y.crend()-roffset));
}
```

Here you have an [online demo](https://ideone.com/yDcUB6)

**Comparing polygons (level 4)**

Now it is not excluded that two consecutive edges are perfectly aligned. So it is possible that a polygon has an additional point which is not relevant for the comparison.

I let you as exercise the handling for this case. But the most natural place to process this special case is when you populate your polygon.

### Second question

To fin the common edges, the easiest way would IMHO be to add the edges to a [`map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), being understood that you would normalize them to ensure that the points are always in the same order.

You could associate to the edge anything you want, for example: a count, a color,  or a container with a pointer to the owning polygon.